# Install Wireshark on MacOS X via brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, wireshark

I installed Wireshark on my mac with the command

```
brew install wireshark
```

but after that, a message told me that I had to *curl* and install *ChmodBPF*, so I did that too.

But there is no command named Wireshark on terminal. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Try `hash -r` to have your shell rehash the newly available commands. Also, check in `/usr/local/bin` for new stuff, like this `ls -lrt /usr/local/bin` - new stuff at bottom of list. Also, make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in your PATH.

Comment: I found that there is no wireshark in /usr/local/bin but there is tshark and rawshark! I am beginner in wireshark, are tshark and wireshark same?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The homebrew package `wireshark` installs the command line util `tshark`. If you want to enable the GUI, then install wireshark like this:

```
brew install wireshark --with-qt
```

If you already have Wireshark installed, do

```
brew reinstall wireshark --with-qt
```

Comment: It works! How did you figure this out? By guessing from `brew cat wireshark`? How did you know to use `with-qt` over `with-gtk+3`?

Comment: I needed --with-qt5 to prevent a weird sizing issue.

Comment: This has been deprecated. Please update answer to: `brew reinstall wireshark --with-qt5`

Comment: @chovy Open a terminal and run `wireshark` to start the GUI.

Comment: Note that the flag `--with-qt5` is now listed as deprecated. One should use `--with-qt`.

Comment: This is not the recommended approach for a GUI application like Wireshark, please see [Radu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43342934/427545) below. At the moment it will also miss features like external name resolution (DNS), codec support and more. Use `brew cask install wireshark` instead.

Comment: > **Error: invalid option: --with-qt**

Comment: brew install --cask wireshark

Answer (score 121):

I suggest using `cask` to create the `.app` binary in your `/Applications` folder (use `reinstall` if already installed):

```
brew install --cask wireshark
```

The advantage of this approach over `brew install wireshark --with-qt` is that more features are enabled without spending a lot of time compiling.

This is also the [recommended](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/17298#issuecomment-325316375) approach for graphical applications and will use the official, feature-complete builds as distributed by the Wireshark developers.

Comment: For me, I had to use `brew install --cask wireshark`. If you use this, you may need to uninstall the non-cask version of wireshark prior to installing the cask.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it in 2022.

Answer (score 24):

I don't think the command `brew install wireshark --with-qt` works anymore as of July 2019 on my laptop running macOS Mojave. So my approach to install Wireshark using Homebrew is to follow the below steps:

1. Update Homebrew: `brew update'
2. Tap the Caskroom/Cask GitHub repository using HTTPS: `brew tap caskroom/cask`
3. Search all known casks for `wireshark`: `brew search wireshark`
4. Find out info about the `wireshark` cask (to be sure): `brew info --cask wireshark`
5. Install the `wireshark` cask: `brew install --cask wireshark`
6. Clean up (just in case): `brew cleanup`

If all goes well, one should see  `wireshark was successfully installed!` after Step 5.

Comment: Type `wireshark` in terminal after all these steps to launch the GUI interface.

Comment: Actually it is now `brew  install --cask wireshark`

Comment: Error: caskroom/cask was moved. Tap homebrew/cask instead.

Comment: I tried cask but now when running wireshark from terminal I get `zsh: command not found: wireshark`

Answer (score 7):

I found that I asked wrong question! Wireshark is gui that use tshark or ... at the back and when I install with brew, it install tshark and ...
So that is reasonable that I could not found wireshark in terminal but I could find tshark!

Comment: ln -s /usr/local/bin/tshark /usr/local/bin/wireshark

Comment: Yes, use the --with-qt flag with brew to get the GUI also.

Comment: i did that. how do i start the gui?

Comment: Just run wireshark in terminal!

Comment: I just ran `brew reinstall wireshark --with-qt5` and the final instruction is the one you want:

    .app bundles were installed.
    Run `brew linkapps wireshark` to symlink these to /Applications.
    ==> Summary
      /usr/local/Cellar/wireshark/2.2.1: 679 files, 145.7M, built in 4 ominutes 33 seconds
    Buddha:~ Jim$ brew linkapps wireshark Linking: /usr/local/opt/wireshark/Wireshark.app Linked 1 app to /Applications Buddha:~ Jim$

Comment: (To hell with mini-Markdown! I'm one half hour closer to my death now and I could have use that half hour much more productively than to try repeatedly to format my comment above as it should be formatted and to fail repeatedly.)

Answer (score 2):

The command works perfectly

```js
 brew install --cask wireshark
```

and install the interface via

```js
brew install --cask wireshark-chmodbpf
```

link to the homebrew page

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/wireshark